# Crosstalk/Ghosting on ADC input

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, filter

I have an ADC circuit which uses AD7689. The inputs of the ADC are driven by LT6010 opamp, and have a low pass filter [image: Schematic].

All 8 channels of the ADC (AD7689) have the same driving circuit. Every other input of the ADC always shows a 3.1mV signal whenever a full scale voltage is applied to the adjacent channel. For example when I apply 5v to channel 1 and short channel 2, channel 2 will read 3.1mV, and all other channels will show 0v. Similar thing happens with channel 3, and 4, and so forth. Now if I remove the capacitor (C152) which is part of the RC filter this problem goes away, and the adjacent ADC input fluctuates between 0.1mV to 0.5mV. An input on channel 1 only effects channel 2. Another thing I noticed was that if I read these channels with longer delay then I don't see this problem. Like If i wait 800 microseconds after reading channel 1, I won't see 3.1mV on channel 2. Is RC filter designed wrong

Comment: https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z0000019KzzSAE